# Why is the covariance matrix inverted in the multivariate Gaussian distribution?

Tags: gaussian

The multivariate gaussian distribution has probability density function:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^k|\mathbf{\Sigma}|}}
\exp\left(-\frac12(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})\right)
$$

(Original at https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVm0K.png)

When comparing the univariate and the multivariate p.d.f, it is interesting to notice the following two facts:

- Dividing by sigma square in the exponent is replaced by multiplying for the inverse of the covariance matrix
- The normalization factor in front of the exponent now contains the determinant of the covariance matrix

The second fact is somehow easier to understand: normalizing the area of the p.d.f now requires to use the determinant of the covariance matrix, since it is the "magnitude" of the space transformation described by the covariance matrix.

The first one is instead more complex to grasp. When we perform this operation

$$
\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})
$$

represents a transformation of the vector $$(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})$$

which itself produces a new transformation, which we will then apply to

$$
(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})^\text{T}
$$

Why is this double linear transformation equivalent to dividing by sigma in a single-dimension case?

Comment: Please add more context: motivation, what's the source of this question? e.g.  Best, read [How to ask a good question on math.se](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C127.4785).

Comment: It's essentially analogous to dividing by (the multivariable equivalent of) the variance. In one variable, all normal distributions are the same, up to central tendency and spread. We subtract the mean and divide by the variance to scale it back to the standard normal. In two or more variables, all normal distributions are the same, up to central tendency, spread, and covariance. So we subtract the mean to correct for the central tendency, and do the bit you showed above to correct for the spread and covariance (in two variables, the "slant of the ellipse").

Comment: We can't just divide, because matrices don't form a field, so we interpose the inverse of the covariance matrix.

Comment: You can show that if $X$ is a random vector and the function you provided is a probability density function (PDF) for $X$ then the covariance matrix for $X$ is $\Sigma$. In other words, $\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix for this distribution.

Answer (score 2):

It must be because it accounts for the dispersion in the exponent. We can use the trace rule to rewrite the exponent:

$$\begin{split}f(\textbf x)&\propto e^{-\frac 12 \text{tr}((x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1}(x-\mu))}\\
&=e^{-\frac 12\text{tr}((x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T\Sigma^{-1})}\end{split}$$

Since $(x-\mu)(x-\mu)^T$ is a measure of dispersion, we can't multiply it by the dispersion again. Therefore, we need to use the inverse of the covariance to make the pdf make sense.

Alternatively, you can think of it in terms of quadratic forms. $x^TAx$ is the matrix equivalent of $ax^2$. So there you have it.